# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error: "Invalid URL (POST /chat/v1/completions)"

Tags: java, android, okhttp, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I followed a tutorial to make an chatgpt app and get this error :

```
Failed to load response due to {
'error' : {
'message' : 'Invalid URL (POST /chat/v1/completions)',
'type':'invalid_request_error',
'param':null,
'code':null
}
}
```

This is my code :

```
JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonBody.put("model", "gpt-3.5-turbo");
            jsonBody.put("messages", question);
            jsonBody.put("max_tokens", 4000);
            jsonBody.put("temperature", 0);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(jsonBody.toString(),JSON);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.openai.com/chat/v1/completions")
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer HIDDEN_KEY")
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .post(body)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                addResponse("Failed to load response due to pd "+e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    JSONObject jsonObject  = null;
                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("choices");
                        String result = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("message");
                        addResponse(result.trim());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }

                }else{
                    addResponse("Failed to load response due to "+response.body().string());
                }
            }
```

I tried changing the model, removing the \chat\ in the URL and send the prompt directly in URL too

I'm new to app making and java coding (but I'm no beginner in coding) so I understand that maybe this code isn't great as I almost only copy and paste the code from the tutorial.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Looks like it should be `/v1/chat/completions` not `/chat/v1/completions`: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat. Also that's strongly suggested by the error messsage you have received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo.

Change this...

```
https://api.openai.com/chat/v1/completions
```

...to this.

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions
```

See the [documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create).

Comment: Ah yes ! At first it was only /v1/completions and it wasn't working so I added /chat/ but at the wrong place.

Sorry for this thread then and thanks for your response !